# GET request call in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

i have one view-controller it contains one label and one button.

i have tried get request method to parse the data.

@"http://adaptiveufest.appspot.com/getAllTimings?companyKey=457f0e98-1cd8-44cd-94a3-a3109a3a64a4"

i tried in this link,but its not working.

i need to make get request and and parse the data from this site and show that result objects in a view controller label.

could any one please help me am very beginner.

Comment: karthik, there are several tutorial are available in net , just try and then ask your question in SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Karthick Samy very very simply you can apply the following code in your .m(Implementation) part

```
  //just give your URL instead of my URL

  NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL     URLWithString:@"http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/search.ashx?query=London&num_of_results=3&format=json&key=xkq544hkar4m69qujdgujn7w"]];

  [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

  [request setValue:@"application/json;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];

  NSError *err;

  NSURLResponse *response;

  NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request   returningResponse:&response error:&err];

 //You need to check response.Once you get the response copy that and paste in ONLINE JSON VIEWER.If you do this clearly you can get the correct results.    

 //After that it depends upon the json format whether it is DICTIONARY or ARRAY 

  NSDictionary *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &err];

  NSArray *array=[[jsonArray objectForKey:@"search_api"]objectForKey:@"result"]; // For Example i give the key is search_api.So according to your response just give your exact key.You must give the correct key.Otherwise it wont give result
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the latest `NSURLSession` library which Apple introduced last year along with iOS 7. Go over [NSURLSession Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/51127/nsurlsession-tutorial) to learn how easy it is to use. There is a lot more help available on the web for the same.

Here's a quick example to get the first 'key' value from the JSON data -

```
- (void)getData {

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

    NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://adaptiveufest.appspot.com/getAllTimings?companyKey=457f0e98-1cd8-44cd-94a3-a3109a3a64a4"];

    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *task = [session downloadTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSURL *location, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

        NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:location];
        NSDictionary *responseDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

        // Do mapping of objects 
        self.keyString = [[responseDictionary valueForKey:@"key"] objectAtIndex:0];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Update value on main thread (UILabel)
            NSLog(@"Value for the first key: %@", self.keyString);
        });
    }];
    [task resume];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`NSURLRequest` is used in ObjectiveC to make get request.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://adaptiveufest.appspot.com/getAllTimings?companyKey=457f0e98-1cd8-44cd-94a3-a3109a3a64a4"]];
    NSError * error = nil;
    NSURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                         returningResponse:&response
                                                     error:&error];
    if (error == nil)
    {
        NSString *returnObject = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[returnObject dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:NULL];
        for (NSDictionary *val in dict) {
            NSLog(@"colorcode : %@",[val objectForKey:@"colorcode"]);
            NSLog(@"key : %@",[val objectForKey:@"key"]);
            NSLog(@"id : %@",[val objectForKey:@"id"]);
            NSLog(@"serviceName : %@",[val objectForKey:@"serviceName"]);
            NSLog(@"status : %@",[val objectForKey:@"status"]);
            NSLog(@"startDateString : %@",[val objectForKey:@"startDateString"]);
            NSLog(@"endDateString : %@",[val objectForKey:@"endDateString"]);
            NSLog(@"serviceCost : %@",[val objectForKey:@"serviceCost"]);
            NSLog(@"f_Key : %@",[val objectForKey:@"f_Key"]);
            NSArray *providerAr = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[val objectForKey:@"providersList"]];
            for (NSString*valStr in providerAr) {
                NSLog(@"providerVal : %@",valStr);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

you can also use [link](https://github.com/rahulsend89/urlHandler)